# Color switches are problematic with footnotes, longtable and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, color, footnotes, longtable

When using the `color` package in its switch form (`\color` cf. `\textcolor`), things can get confused using certain packages, with footnotes, and with section headings. The section headings issue was discussed in [another of my questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75809) but, even with the `\zcolor` robust command definition suggested by David Carlisle (the color author) there, this still causes problems with footnotes, and the `longtable` and `hyperref` packages.

See the LaTeX source below:

(a) Footnotes from coloured text lose their colour.

(b) `hyperref` URLs within footnotes get the colour back! (This doesn't happen if using the `url` package instead.)

(c) Floating longtables can/will get the color of text on the page they float to, even when defined in a non-coloured area. (Using `table` and `tabular` doesn't have this problem. I used the `afterpage` package to force the table to be on the next page, and assume the problem still exists if it 'naturally' did.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}

%\usepackage{url}      % URLs in footnotes consistent (no color) if use this instead
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvips]{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\startToDo}{\color{Purple}}
\newcommand{\stopToDo}{\color{Black}}

\author{Stuart Rossiter}
\title{Color weirdness test}
\date{4th November 2013}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\startToDo          % Works with titles
\section{Wibble Wobble}
\lipsum[1-4]
What about footnote weirdness?\footnote{A profound footnote that should be
colored with a URL:
\url{http://wibblewobble.org}.}
\stopToDo

\lipsum[1-3]

\afterpage{         % Just to force it to be on page with colored text
\begin{longtable}{ccc}      % Table is OK if use normal table and tabular
%\begin{table}
%\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\caption{An astonishing table that shouldn't be coloured.}
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{longtable}
}

\section{Wobble Wibble}

\startToDo
\lipsum
\stopToDo

\end{document}
```

I guess my question is:

Can my use of `color` be 'fixed' to work robustly in all such scenarios?

(David's answer to my [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75809) suggests `color` is fundamentally problematic in such  contorted constructs, and can't be 'fixed' itself.)

As the `\startToDo` and `\stopToDo` (custom) macros suggest, I use `color` to mark-up to-do text. I'll ask a separate question about better alternatives (that avoid these colour issues).

Comment: no time now, may look this evening, but the important thing to remember is whatever has gone wrong it's not my fault:-) floats explicitly normalise the color so to copy that behaviour use `\afterpage{{\normalcolor \begin{longtable}....}}`

Comment: Thanks David. I've slightly changed the title to make it seem less 'accusing' of the color package! I can imagine that the multi-pass way stuff like longtable and hyperref work makes things very tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `color` options not to use `dvips` explicitly so it works with `latex/dvips` and with `pdflatex` (you should rarely need to give the driver option)

I added a `\normalcolor` reset to `\afterpage` to mimic the `\normalcolor` that floats do.

Conversely I added a `\startToDo`  to the footnote to overcome the color reset that footnotes do so the footnote comes out Purple.

I think this now makes the same result with pdflatex or latex/dvips/ps2pdf and I think it's the result you intended...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}

%\usepackage{url}      % URLs in footnotes consistent (no color) if use this instead
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\startToDo}{\color{Purple}}
\newcommand{\stopToDo}{\color{Black}}

\author{Stuart Rossiter}
\title{Color weirdness test}
\date{4th November 2013}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\startToDo          % Works with titles
\section{Wibble Wobble}
\lipsum[1-4]
What about footnote weirdness?\footnote{\startToDo A profound footnote that should be
colored with a URL:
\url{http://wibblewobble.org}.}
\stopToDo

\lipsum[1-3]

\afterpage{{\normalcolor        % Just to force it to be on page with colored text
\begin{longtable}{ccc}      % Table is OK if use normal table and tabular
%\begin{table}
%\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\caption{An astonishing table that shouldn't be coloured.}
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{longtable}
}}

\section{Wobble Wibble}

\startToDo
\lipsum
\stopToDo

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great; will try it out soon. To be clear about the floating longtables issue ((c) in my question), are you saying that this *was* the result of explicitly using `afterpage`, and that it wouldn't happen if the longtable 'naturally' floated to a page with coloured text (i.e., my assumption in the question is wrong?).

Comment: @monsieurRigsby well longtables don't float so the issue doesn't arise but things that do float have to normalize colour (and fonts and other things) in case they float into areas with different settings.