# Cross-referencing on 2 kinds of end-footnotes (separated and with different coloured numbers)

Tags: cross-referencing, color, endnotes

In the beginning I used parnotes and endnotes to distinguish between the 2 seperated kinds of end-footnotes:

- Attention: to be able to compile the first "grey box" of trial code, one must [download the `hyperendnotes`-"package"- (.sty file)](https://github.com/bibliogum/latexamu/blob/master/hyperendnotes.sty).
- Remark: if you would like to learn more on what `\patchcmd{..}{..}{..}{..}` and `\usepackage{etoolbox}` are doing, see  [another "sub"-post of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219000/a-question-about-using-a-renewcommand-to-adapt-a-package/219007#219007).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changepage} % \begin{adjustwidth}{...cm}{...cm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref} % colors endnotes red --- for hyperlinks --- hyperref permits use of color{blue}{...}
\usepackage{endnotes} % \endnote{...}
\input{hyperendnotes.sty} % LOADS (needs \usepackage{hyperref}) hyperendnotes.sty; which can be downloaded at
% https://github.com/bibliogum/latexamu/blob/master/hyperendnotes.sty

\def\enoteheading{} % endnotes without standard heading

\usepackage[breakwithin, roman]{parnotes} % parnotes

\makeatletter % needed for \renewcommand{...} and \patchcmd{...}
\renewcommand{\parnotemarkfmt}[1]{{{\color{blue}\PN@mark@set{#1}\hspace{0.5mm}}}} % color parnotes blue --- tweaks spacing --- adjusts size of parnotes to look like hyperendnotes (part 1)
\usepackage{etoolbox} % \patchcmd{...}
\patchcmd{\PN@parnote@real}
  {\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}}
  {\textsuperscript{\hspace{1.23mm}\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}\hspace{-0.67mm}}}
  {}{} % <<< adjusts size of parnotes to look like hyperendnotes (part 2) --- thanks a lot for this part @egreg; at
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219000/a-question-about-using-a-renewcommand-to-adapt-a-package/219007#219007
\makeatother % needed for \renewcommand{...} and \patchcmd{...}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text \parnote{A parnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \endnote{An endnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \endnote{Another endnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \parnote{Another parnote} \par
\noindent \textbf{Parnotes}
\parnotes
\textbf{Endnotes} \par
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.49mm}{0cm}
\theendnotes
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

### So they *were* seperated and "labeled" just fine (even when the 2 "kinds" of endnotes are interwoven).

### But that *didn't* get cross-referencing (clickable links) on the parnotes ...

Loading `hyperendnotes.sty` only puts clickable cross-referenced "links" on the `\endnote{...}`'s, but not on the `\parnote{...}`'s.

---

So user @cfr hinted at the `enotez`-package. I've found `\usepackage{enotez}` at least easier, since it doesn't require to load the extra `hyperendnotes.sty` any more.

In this second trial I only used endnotes (I dropped parnotes, since I wasn't able to get clickable hyperlinks on them.

---

In this second trial I only used endnotes (I dropped parnotes, since I wasn't able to get clickable hyperlinks on them.

- Attention: This second "grey box" of trial code requires to compile two times. (due to the `enotez`-package).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enotez}
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{section}{paragraph}{heading={}}
\setenotez{backref=true, list-style=section, reset, split-title=\noindent}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}

Som text here \endnote{Endnote}. \par
Some more text \endnote{Endnote} before the first call of \colorbox{gray!20}{\textbackslash printendnotes}. 

\vspace{1em} \textbf{A first person's endnotes} \printendnotes \vspace{1em}

\setenotez{counter-format={roman}} \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

See? I can get clickable endnotes in two different colours, which is what I wanted. \endnote{Endnote}. \par {\large{But the problem is that ALL of the endnotes (of a certain colour) have to be grouped together and originate before the first \colorbox{gray!20}{\textbackslash printendnotes} and before ALL of the other endnotes (of another colour): there is no freedom to use the endnotes "interwoven", unfortunately.}} \endnote{Endnote}.


\vspace{1em} \textbf{A second person's endnotes} \printendnotes \vspace{2em}

\setenotez{counter-format={arabic}} \hypersetup{linkcolor=red}

You can get both footnote sections to truly follow each-other at the end of the document \endnote{Endnote} (which is what i wanted), by using a lot of \colorbox{gray!20}{\textbackslash vspace}'s (see the .tex-code below this line). But having to constantly adjust the \colorbox{gray!20}{\textbackslash vspace}'s doesn't seem very elegant at all. \endnote{Endnote}

\vspace{8.2em}% extra \vspace{...} to group the endnote sections together at the end of the .pdf

\vspace{1em} \textbf{A first person's endnotes} \printendnotes \vspace{1em}

\setenotez{counter-format={roman}} \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\vspace{-15em}% extra \vspace{...} to group the endnote sections together at the end of the .pdf

See?\endnote{Endnote} Now the the sections are really together \endnote{Endnote} at the very end of the document. \par However: the {\large{origins of the two different types of endnotes still have to be grouped together, and cannot get interwoven, unfortunately.}}

\vspace{8em}% extra \vspace{...} to group the endnote sections together at the end of the .pdf

\vspace{1em} \textbf{A second person's endnotes} \printendnotes \vspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

### Now there *is* cross-referencing (clickable links) on all of the endnotes!

### But the different kinds of endnotes *can no longer be* interwoven.

There is no way to correctly code-label the different "types" of endnotes this way (without the parnotes). If "interwoven" the two "types" wouldn't be numbered and placed seperately at the bottom of the document.

---

So, in brief. Either one of the following could solve my problem.

Either:

- getting cross-references on parnotes.

Or (when working with cross-referencable endnotes):

- label the "type(-of-endnote)" (to have seperate numbering, colour and perhaps numerals) and have them printed seperately.

---

I started wondering whether or not a solution could be offered *not* using standard parnotes, endnotes or footnotes at all? But just have other code-labels to distinguish between two types of "notes", add some superscript, numbering, colouring (to "fake" endnotes). And then have them printed seperately? Perhaps (as a last resort) with `biblatex`?

I guess this "faking" or "defining footnotes autonomously" was done at the german Q-A-site texwelt: [here](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4058/wie-kann-ich-beliebig-viele-farblich-abgesetzte-anmerkungen-anlegen-und-verarbeiten) or [here](http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3964/wie-kann-ich-parameter-an-eine-definition-ubergeben). I'll post an english (slightly adapted) version below:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\newnotestype[2]{%
\newcounter{#1note}%
\expandafter\newwrite\csname the#1notes\endcsname
\expandafter\immediate\expandafter\openout\csname
the#1notes\endcsname=\jobname.#1\relax %
\expandafter\newcommand\csname  #1note\endcsname[1]{%
\stepcounter{#1note}%
{%
\tiny\textsuperscript\expandafter\textcolor{#2}{{%
\raisebox{1ex}{\hbox{\kern-0.0em\csname
the#1note\endcsname\kern-0.0em}}}}%
\expandafter\immediate\expandafter\write\csname the#1notes\endcsname%
{\csname the#1note\endcsname\ \unexpanded{##1 \par}}%
}}%

\expandafter\newcommand\csname display#1notes\endcsname[1]{%
\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
\expandafter\immediate\expandafter\closeout%
\csname the#1notes\endcsname%
\par\tiny\expandafter\textcolor{#2}{\textbf{##1}}\par%
\input\jobname.#1%
}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%

\newnotestype{first}{red}
\newnotestype{second}{blue}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

This is the test-text \firstnote{Endnote} \secondnote{Endnote} , some more \firstnote{Endnote} test-text, some more  \secondnote{Endnote} test-text \secondnote{Endnote}. 

%%%%%%%%%%%

\displayfirstnotes{A first person's endnotes}
\displaysecondnotes{A second person's endnotes}

\end{document}
```

### Now the different kinds of endnotes *can be* labeled easily and interwoven again.

### But again there is *no more* cross-referencing (clickable links) on *any* of the endnotes.

The simple `\usepackage{hyperref}` isn't working anymore, since the footnotes aren't actual "footnotes": they are "faked" to look like them.

So does anyone know of an elegant solution to get cross-referencing (clickable links) on these "objects"?

Some other question:

- This last (third) trial also colours the endnotes-headers, but *not* the endnote-numbers (at least not where the endnotes are printed). If anyone could get colour on the endnote-numbering there as well, that would be welcome.
- Also: this way, there *no longer* seems to be an easy way to switch from arabic numberals to roman (in general, and in particular for one "type" of endnote)?

*Many thanks.*

Comment: Have you considered using `endnotez` which supports `hyperref` out-of-the-box? Also, have you read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8474/)? I don't know if that's the code you are using or not.

Comment: I meant `enotez`. By the way, `\bf` was deprecated 20+ years ago. It is not a LaTeX-2e command. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` instead.

Comment: @cfr; You referred to [the post about `hyperendnotes.sty`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8474/). This is indeed the input I used in the first trial ("grey box" of code). However, I haven't in the second trial: there I fiddled around with the `enotez`-package because of your hint). Thanks for the notice about bold typesetting as well.

Comment: One other thought: have you looked at [eledmac](http://ctan.org/pkg/eledmac)? It is a package for typesetting critical editions. It can handle multiple series of endnotes or footnotes, and does hyperlinks. Note that I've never used it so I don't know whether all of this works well together in the way you desire, but I looked through the manual and I think it would be worth considering given that nobody has so far suggested an answer here.

Comment: Or [edmargin](http://ctan.org/pkg/edmargin) might be simpler.

Comment: @cfr. I've looked up [eledmac](http://ctan.org/pkg/eledmac) very briefly, but I didn't found a way *NOT* to have those little "line-numbers" in front of each line. I might check it out again. But unfortunately, it takes about a full day (if not longer) worth of time for me to discover a new package... Do you think [edmargin](http://ctan.org/pkg/edmargin) does hyperlinks too? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps new jigsaw pieces either here: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4058/wie-kann-ich-beliebig-viele-farblich-abgesetzte-anmerkungen-anlegen-und-verarbeiten, or here: http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3964/wie-kann-ich-parameter-an-eine-definition-ubergeben. --- I don't know if these other links will help: http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5918/wie-kann-ich-footcite-im-caption-einer-gleitumgebung-verwenden, and http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5965/wie-bekomme-ich-footcite-und-footnote-in-die-multicols. --- I posted a third trial today.

Comment: Just writing a couple more related links to be reviewed: [Hyperref footnotes and section ref colors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117943/hyperref-footnotes-and-section-ref-colors?rq=1), [Color switches are problematic with footnotes, longtable and hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142228/color-switches-are-problematic-with-footnotes-longtable-and-hyperref?rq=1) and [Change the color of footnote marker in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26693/change-the-color-of-footnote-marker-in-latex).

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried using the `sepfootnotes` package (don't know if it works with links but I know it supports different classes of notes)

Comment: @clemens I haven't. Can you suggest a MWE? :)

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I'd have to look up `sepfootnotes`' manual so any MWE I could suggest would be as good as if you'd try on your own, I guess

Comment: @clemens Ok, no problem. As far as I understand from the [documentation](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/sepfootnotes/sepfootnotes.pdf) @ [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes), I can find no way of achieving the desired result. There is no mention of linkable footnotes indeed, as you had guessed. Colours (or other lay-out adjustability) are also not discussed. It seems to me this package is mainly for *defining the contents of a note in 1 .tex-file, while typesetting that note in another .tex-file*.