# A question about using a \renewcommand to adapt a package

Tags: macros, packages, parnotes

This article is a sub-question of: [Cross-referencing on 2 kinds of end-footnotes (separated and with different coloured numbers)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218960/cross-referencing-in-two-kinds-of-end-footnotes-separated-and-with-different-co)

---

Hi,

I am trying to adapt a package called parnotes (which can be called using `\usepackage{parnotes}`. Its original source code can be downloaded [at CTAN here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes).

The line of code I want to "adapt" (i.e. change when implemented in another .tex-document) lives inside the following piece:

```
\long\def\PN@parnote@real#1{
   \global\advance\c@PN@t\@ne

    \g@addto@macro\PN@text{

        \global\advance\c@PN@n\@ne
        \parnotemarkfmt{PN@n}\nolinebreak\thinspace#1

            \unless\ifnum\c@PN@n=\c@PN@t
                \parnoteintercmd
            \fi
        }
    \unskip\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}
}
```

The only line I want to be change is the last one. I would like it to become:

```
    \unskip\textsuperscript{\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}}
```

I know when this change performs perfect (I tweaked the downloadable source code at CTAN), but I would like to ask you for help, since I don't know how to change this line of code from outside (i.e. from a new .tex-file).

I would think (since I was able to adapt another line of code of the source this way) one would use in the preamble of a new .tex-document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{...???...}
\makeatother
```

Or perhaps someone knows an alternative way using `\let ...`?

*Many thanks in advance.*

Comment: The default definition of `\parnotemarkfmt` already has `\textsuperscript`. Why would you want to add another level of superscripting?

Comment: @egreg; I am trying to make the parnotes behave exactly like cross-referenced ("hyperlinked") endnotes which use hyperendnotes.

---

The hyperendnotes package [can be found here](https://github.com/bibliogum/latexamu/blob/master/hyperendnotes.sty) and can be included by addding `\input{hyperendnotes.sty}`to the preamble.

---

These hyperendnotes-numbers have a different look then normal endnotes (they are larger, but only below `\theendnotes`; not in the "body"-text, where any footnote-number is first mentioned). Hence displacing the `\textsuperscript`. I will show a MWE below your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parnotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{autopn}
Text\parnote{parnote}

Text
\end{autopn}

\end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]

With your proposed change it would become

[image]

that's definitely bad, because the exponent is too high (besides being too small, but this is a question of taste).

The “easy” way, with which I produced the example, is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\PN@parnote@real}
  {\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}}
  {\textsuperscript{\parnotemarkfmt{PN@t}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

There are many examples of how `\patchcmd` can be used; see, for instance, [Please tutor the usage of patchcmd and xpatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/please-tutor-the-usage-of-patchcmd-and-xpatch)

However, in this case this is the wrong way to go. Indeed, the package provides `\parnotemarkfmt` exactly for the purpose of formatting the marker in text.

Its definition by the package is

```
\providecommand{\parnotemarkfmt}[1]{\textsuperscript{\PN@mark@set{#1}}}
```

(by the way, `\newcommand` should be used here, but it's of no consequence for the topic at hand). As you see, `\textsuperscript` is used. For information, `\PN@mark@set` is, by default, the same as `\arabic`.

If you want to reduce the size of the exponent, you can simply change the definition of `\parnotemarkfmt`. If you want a smaller exponent, you can define a `\textsmallsuperscript` macro based on what `\textsuperscript` does:

```
% latex.ltx, line 6017:
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsuperscript[1]{%
  \@textsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\@textsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
```

So we can do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsmallsuperscript[1]{%
  \vincent@textsmallsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\vincent@textsmallsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\ssf@size\z@#1}}}}}
```

Using a prefix before the “internal macro marker” `@` is good practice.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parnotes}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsmallsuperscript[1]{%
  \vincent@textsmallsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\vincent@textsmallsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\ssf@size\z@#1}}}}}% <--- use scriptscriptsize

\renewcommand{\parnotemarkfmt}[1]{\textsmallsuperscript{\PN@mark@set{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{autopn}
Text\parnote{parnote}

Text
\end{autopn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. You can see [the implementation in another post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218960/cross-referencing-on-two-kinds-of-end-footnotes-separated-and-with-different-co).

---

One last question:

What is really nice about the parnotes is that they have a fixed indent: note that when reaching 2 digits (at number 10), the parnotes don't shift to the right, while the endnotes do? --- I wonder if the indent of the endnotes could become fixed as well?

Comment: Note that with parnotes rev. 2, the `\renewcommand` line will need to change to `\renewcommand{\parnotecusmarkfmt}[1]{\textsmallsuperscript{#1}}`.

Comment: @rdhs When will it be available?

Comment: I've already uploaded it to CTAN, so give it a day or so. Alternatively, get it from my GitHub page: https://github.com/chelh/LaTeX-parnotes/releases