# Highlighting text for review

Tags: highlighting, notes

I am looking for a way to highlight sections, sentences, etc for review without breaking the paragraphs up.

I have tried the package `todonotes`, but I couldn't get the underlining to work with sentences spanning multiple lines.

Comment: You can use `\emph{some text}` to highlight some part of your text.

Comment: Do you mean something _like_ `todonotes` but kind of a third mode (despite margin and an own paragraph), that is inline and colors the highlighted part (including a border)?

Comment: @Ronny A way to highlight part (from a single word to a whole paragraph) of my report such that I can express what I don't like about a that part of the report to my supervisor for his feedback.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should give us a small example of what you have tried so far. `todonotes` is able to mark multiple paragraphs (I believe). If you give us some code, we can help you fixing it.

Comment: Related to various underlining techniques: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons .  And here are ways to mark draft text: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text .

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I like the text above a sentence solution.

Comment: If that approach I cited worked out for you, we could call this question a duplicate of  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text.  Was that the case?