# How to track changes that need to be retranslated?

Tags: languages, linux, changes

I often need to write multilingual documents. I usually put the translations into a macro like this, so that I can quickly render documents with either of the languages or both, but modify the syntax if necessary.

```
\text{This is the English translation.}{这是中文的发言。}
```

I focus on the English primarily, then add the other language latter and get help with challenging parts. The problem is, sometimes I will go back through the document, making many small corrections, it is difficult to remember which parts were changed and thus require and updated translation.

Is there any tool for keeping track of the changes occurring to the English and corresponding updates to the other language?

Comment: For tracking changes I am a big fan of [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff).

Comment: It is several qestions regarding this topic. Search for 'track changes' at this site. See for example [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65453/track-changes-in-latex)

Comment: Standard revision-tracking just provide a history of changes, right? Do they provide an indication of which things need to be updated to match changes?

Comment: Is adding an inline "to-do note" of one kind or another what you seek?  For example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text/142258#142258